# Changing given observed data of a specific shape from UTC to LST in python

Tags: python, utc, data-conversion

I have 3-hourly temperature data for 39 years. The shape of the data is data = (39,12,31,8) for 39 years, 12 months, 31 days, and 8 hours in UTC (which is 0000, 0300, 0600, 0900, 1200, 1500, 1800, and 2100). I want to change this dataframe to UTC+6 (Dhaka).

I will add the first few values of the array for a clearer understanding. This is the 3-hourly temperature for the first 5 days of January in the first year.

```
array([[15.4, 14.2, 14.7, 16.6, 23.4, 25. , 19.5, 17.7],
       [ 9.9,  8.2,  8. , 16.8, 22.2, 23.8, 17. , 12.5],
       [10.4,  9.6,  7.2, 15.4, 20.9, 22. , 15.8, 12. ],
       [11.5, 10. ,  8. , 14.4, 22.1, 23.7, 19. , 12.1],
       [13.5, 11.8,  9. , 18.1, 24. , 26.2, 19. , 15. ]])
```

I used the numpy.roll function to roll the data. But that doesn't actually work because if I change the hours, then for 1800 and 2100 UTC, the date changes too. Those two hours become the 0000 and 0300 LST of the next day.
So my expected array is as the array below,

```
array([[NaN, NaN, 15.4, 14.2, 14.7, 16.6, 23.4, 25. ],
       [19.5, 17.7, 9.9,  8.2, 8. , 16.8, 22.2, 23.8],
       [17. , 12.5, 10.4,  9.6, 7.2, 15.4, 20.9, 22.],
       [15.8, 12., 11.5, 10. , 8. , 14.4, 22.1, 23.7],
       [19. , 12.1, 13.5, 11.8, 9. , 18.1, 24., 26.2]])
```

Using the datetime module or any other module, how can I change the time to LST like this?

Comment: Rolling your values forward seems an easy way out, but as you're dealing with multi-year data, don't you want to take into account the [DST shift in 2009](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/bangladesh/dhaka)? Also, why can't you work in UTC time, and only do the conversion at the end when you want to display your data?

Comment: As for the DST shift in 2009, I think I have to consider that.  And I need to convert the  data because I'm currently working with Urban Heat Islands (UHI) and day/nighttime UHI intensities. I'm doing multiple linear regression between different variables for day/nighttime There is no problem in selecting the daytime hours, but, for nighttime I selected the 21 and 03 LST and I want these two hours on the same day. I'm also wondering whether taking the 03 and 21 LST of the same day is appropriate or not because they are 18 hours apart, while the daytime hours are 6 hours apart (09 and 15 LST)